# MPU 6050 only reads 0 in output

Tags: mpu6050

I am new to using MPU 6050. I am stuck at a basic code of getting readings from the sensor. The code I used is attached below. Its the one with GY 521 breakout board. Concluding that my sensor is broken I have changed sensor and now using the third one. Still no luck. FYI I have run the i2c scanner code to check whether arduino(nano) can detect the sensor. The code responds to all the sensors I tried. I have no clue what I am doing wrong. If someone could provide some suggestions it would be helpful

```
    MPU6050 Triple Axis Gyroscope & Accelerometer. Simple Gyroscope Example.
    Read more: http://www.jarzebski.pl/arduino/czujniki-i-sensory/3-osiowy-zyroskop-i-akcelerometr-mpu6050.html
    GIT: https://github.com/jarzebski/Arduino-MPU6050
    Web: http://www.jarzebski.pl
    (c) 2014 by Korneliusz Jarzebski
*/

#include <Wire.h>
#include <MPU6050.h>

MPU6050 mpu;

void setup() 
{
  Serial.begin(115200);

  // Initialize MPU6050
  Serial.println("Initialize MPU6050");
  while(!mpu.begin(MPU6050_SCALE_2000DPS, MPU6050_RANGE_2G))
  {
    Serial.println("Could not find a valid MPU6050 sensor, check wiring!");
    delay(500);
  }
  
  // If you want, you can set gyroscope offsets
  // mpu.setGyroOffsetX(155);
  // mpu.setGyroOffsetY(15);
  // mpu.setGyroOffsetZ(15);
  
  // Calibrate gyroscope. The calibration must be at rest.
  // If you don't want calibrate, comment this line.
  mpu.calibrateGyro();

  // Set threshold sensivty. Default 3.
  // If you don't want use threshold, comment this line or set 0.
  mpu.setThreshold(3);
  
  // Check settings
  checkSettings();
}

void checkSettings()
{
  Serial.println();
  
  Serial.print(" * Sleep Mode:        ");
  Serial.println(mpu.getSleepEnabled() ? "Enabled" : "Disabled");
  
  Serial.print(" * Clock Source:      ");
  switch(mpu.getClockSource())
  {
    case MPU6050_CLOCK_KEEP_RESET:     Serial.println("Stops the clock and keeps the timing generator in reset"); break;
    case MPU6050_CLOCK_EXTERNAL_19MHZ: Serial.println("PLL with external 19.2MHz reference"); break;
    case MPU6050_CLOCK_EXTERNAL_32KHZ: Serial.println("PLL with external 32.768kHz reference"); break;
    case MPU6050_CLOCK_PLL_ZGYRO:      Serial.println("PLL with Z axis gyroscope reference"); break;
    case MPU6050_CLOCK_PLL_YGYRO:      Serial.println("PLL with Y axis gyroscope reference"); break;
    case MPU6050_CLOCK_PLL_XGYRO:      Serial.println("PLL with X axis gyroscope reference"); break;
    case MPU6050_CLOCK_INTERNAL_8MHZ:  Serial.println("Internal 8MHz oscillator"); break;
  }
  
  Serial.print(" * Gyroscope:         ");
  switch(mpu.getScale())
  {
    case MPU6050_SCALE_2000DPS:        Serial.println("2000 dps"); break;
    case MPU6050_SCALE_1000DPS:        Serial.println("1000 dps"); break;
    case MPU6050_SCALE_500DPS:         Serial.println("500 dps"); break;
    case MPU6050_SCALE_250DPS:         Serial.println("250 dps"); break;
  } 
  
  Serial.print(" * Gyroscope offsets: ");
  Serial.print(mpu.getGyroOffsetX());
  Serial.print(" / ");
  Serial.print(mpu.getGyroOffsetY());
  Serial.print(" / ");
  Serial.println(mpu.getGyroOffsetZ());
  
  Serial.println();
}

void loop()
{
  Vector rawGyro = mpu.readRawGyro();
  Vector normGyro = mpu.readNormalizeGyro();

  Serial.print(" Xraw = ");
  Serial.print(rawGyro.XAxis);
  Serial.print(" Yraw = ");
  Serial.print(rawGyro.YAxis);
  Serial.print(" Zraw = ");
  Serial.println(rawGyro.ZAxis);

  Serial.print(" Xnorm = ");
  Serial.print(normGyro.XAxis);
  Serial.print(" Ynorm = ");
  Serial.print(normGyro.YAxis);
  Serial.print(" Znorm = ");
  Serial.println(normGyro.ZAxis);
  
  delay(10);
}
```

Comment: Could you provide a schematic of how you connected everything together? The MPU-6050 is a 3.3 V device while the Arduino is 5 V. Also the GY 521 has an onboard 3.3 V regulator that should be supplied with 5 V rather than 3.3 V. More info on [Arduino Plaground](https://playground.arduino.cc/Main/MPU-6050/) and [schematic diagram](https://playground.arduino.cc/uploads/Main/MPU6050-V1-SCH/index.jpg)

Answer (score 2):

I hope it is useful for debugging ...

Only a sketch I found ([here](https://playground.arduino.cc/Main/MPU-6050/#short)), not remembering if I have tested ...

```cpp
// MPU-6050 Short Example Sketch
// By Arduino User JohnChi
// August 17, 2014
// Public Domain
#include<Wire.h>
const int MPU_addr=0x68;  // I2C address of the MPU-6050
int16_t AcX,AcY,AcZ,Tmp,GyX,GyY,GyZ;
void setup(){
  Wire.begin();
  Wire.beginTransmission(MPU_addr);
  Wire.write(0x6B);  // PWR_MGMT_1 register
  Wire.write(0);     // set to zero (wakes up the MPU-6050)
  Wire.endTransmission(true);
  Serial.begin(9600);
}
void loop(){
  Wire.beginTransmission(MPU_addr);
  Wire.write(0x3B);  // starting with register 0x3B (ACCEL_XOUT_H)
  Wire.endTransmission(false);
  Wire.requestFrom(MPU_addr,14,true);  // request a total of 14 registers
  AcX=Wire.read()<<8|Wire.read();  // 0x3B (ACCEL_XOUT_H) & 0x3C (ACCEL_XOUT_L)    
  AcY=Wire.read()<<8|Wire.read();  // 0x3D (ACCEL_YOUT_H) & 0x3E (ACCEL_YOUT_L)
  AcZ=Wire.read()<<8|Wire.read();  // 0x3F (ACCEL_ZOUT_H) & 0x40 (ACCEL_ZOUT_L)
  Tmp=Wire.read()<<8|Wire.read();  // 0x41 (TEMP_OUT_H) & 0x42 (TEMP_OUT_L)
  GyX=Wire.read()<<8|Wire.read();  // 0x43 (GYRO_XOUT_H) & 0x44 (GYRO_XOUT_L)
  GyY=Wire.read()<<8|Wire.read();  // 0x45 (GYRO_YOUT_H) & 0x46 (GYRO_YOUT_L)
  GyZ=Wire.read()<<8|Wire.read();  // 0x47 (GYRO_ZOUT_H) & 0x48 (GYRO_ZOUT_L)
  Serial.print("AcX = "); Serial.print(AcX);
  Serial.print(" | AcY = "); Serial.print(AcY);
  Serial.print(" | AcZ = "); Serial.print(AcZ);
  Serial.print(" | Tmp = "); Serial.print(Tmp/340.00+36.53);  //equation for temperature in degrees C from datasheet
  Serial.print(" | GyX = "); Serial.print(GyX);
  Serial.print(" | GyY = "); Serial.print(GyY);
  Serial.print(" | GyZ = "); Serial.println(GyZ);
  delay(333);
}
```

There is also a [long example sketch](https://playground.arduino.cc/Main/MPU-6050/#sketch) ...

Answer (score 1):

You do not tell us what is the problem so my guess is address or level.
If you get "Could not find a valid MPU6050 sensor, check wiring!" this is an address problem. By default MP6050 uses x068 as I2C address. If you have something else connected to the bus, there might be a conflict. If so, connect AD0 to 3.3V (pull-up with a 2.2kOhms resistor) to set address to 0x69 (use I2C scanner in /example/wire to make sure).
If you see zeros, this might be a logic level problem:
To elaborate on the previous answer, the MP6050 is a 3.3V device. The GY 521 circuit has a voltage regulator (5V->3.3V) bUt on output it still uses 3.3V TTL logic level. With some noise, bad contacts or long wires, the Arduino may fail to read the I2C properly. Had similar problems, solved using a bidirectional logic level shifter between a Uno and the MPU6050. You can get pre-assembled 4-channels board (same size as GY521 board) for ~ 1US$. I hope this helps